# Getting first byte in a char* buffer

Tags: c++, c

I have a char* buffer and I am interested in looking at the first byte in the char* buffer, what is the most optimal way to go about this.

EDIT: Based on the negative votes I might want to explain why this question, I am aware of methods but in the code base that I have been looking for getting first byte people do all kinds of crazy things  like do a copy of the buffer , copy it to a stream and then do a get.

Comment: if by optimum you mean "fastest", just use either Johannes's or Josh's answer. micro-optimizing is stupid.

Comment: Johannes' answer is optimum anyway -- it compiles to a single indexed load op.

Comment: I haven't seen a compiler that treats buffer[0] differently from *buffer since the days of pcc.

Comment: One wonders why on earth you would care about such a thing? If it's speed you want, you should probably be reading more than one byte at a time from your buffer!

Comment: Is this really a question? Homework?

Comment: Nope this is not a homework, i am aware of the methods but I wanted to get an opinion. I have added subjective to the tags hopefully.

Comment: If people are really doing that in your code base I think it's time for a quick email to http://thedailywtf.com/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just use

```
char firstByte = buffer[0];
```

Comment: But is it optimum? That costs a whole cycle! ;)

Comment: It could be more if buffer has been paged out - that could be hundreds of cycles.  Just to be sure, you should probably lock that memory into RAM so no paging is going to happen.

Comment: It's possible to ensure some memory doesn't get paged out?

Comment: In Windows, you can look at VirtualLock (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366895.aspx) - but my comment about paging was sarcastic and I don't recommend this as an actual performance enhancing technique.

Answer (score 13):

Or this:

```
char firstByte = *buffer;
```

For clarification, there's no difference between `*buffer` and `buffer[0]`, since the latter is really just shorthand for `*(buffer + 0*sizeof(char))`, and any compiler is going to be smart enough to replace that with `*(buffer+0)` and then `*buffer`.  So the choice is really whichever is clearest in the context you are using it, not how efficient each one is.

Answer (score 5):

```
char *buffer = {'h','e','l','l','o','\0'};
```

or:

```
char *buffer = "hello";
```

or:

```
char buffer[6] = {'h','e','l','l','o','\0'};
```

and to get the first byte:

```
char firstChar = buffer[0];
```

or:

```
char firstChar = *buffer; // since the buffer pointer points to the first element in the array
```

Comment: {'h','e','l','l','o','\0'} has six elements.

Comment: There is quite the diffence between char *buffer = "hello"; and char buffer[] = "hello";

Comment: Right, I fixed "is equal" to "or".

Answer (score 2):

If you're determined to micro-optimize, you should know that every compiler made in this millennium should produce exactly the same machine code for "c = *buffer" and "c = buffer[0]".

Comment: Even my toy class-project compiler can do this optimization ;)

Comment: Since buffer[0] is defined as *(buffer + 0 * sizeof(char)), it isn't a difficult optimization.  It's a straight transform, followed by a little precalculation.  I'd be shocked at a publicly available compiler that missed this one.

Answer (score 1):

```
char first = someCharPtr[0];
```

or

```
char first = *someCharPtr;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just as a clarification of what several people have mentioned--that:

```
buffer[0]
```

is equivalent to

```
*(buffer + 0*sizeof(char))
```

That's not technically true if you assume that's literal C code (i.e. not pseudo code), although that's what the compiler is doing for you.

Because of pointer arithmetic, when you add an integer to a pointer, it is automatically multiplied by `sizeof(*pointer)`, so it should really be:

```
*(buffer + 0)
```

Although, since `sizeof(char)` is defined to be 1, it is actually equivalent in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
char* c_ptr;
char first_char;

first_char = c_ptr[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Good for x86 platforms...

```
char firstByte;

__asm {
   mov al, [buffer]
   mov [firstByte], al
}
```